# Detailed exposition for proof of Localization Lemma in paper "Random Walks in a Convex Body and an Improved Volume Algorithm"

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hull

I've begun reading the paper "Random Walks in a Convex Body and an Improved Volume Algorithm" by Lovász-Simonovits ('93). Although the paper for the most part is pretty self-contained and easy to read, the proof of the Localization lemma seems to be rather obtuse to me. Importantly there are certain statements that I'm having a hard part understanding. I would love to know any good exposition and/or if someone could help me out with these questions.

- Under Claim 2, there is this following statement: It follows by a standard compactness arguments that such a pair of points and
  function $\psi$ exists. I am having a hard time understanding this argument.
- I'm having a hard time understanding what the convex body $K^\prime$ actually represents. You can give me an example in the case of 2-D or 3-D convex bodies.
- Can anyone explain what the body $L_A$ exactly represents?

Really appreciate any help that I can get

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53411/5038